# Global User Notification Widget

Tags: dashboard-widgets, dashboard

Is it possible to create a Custom Widget that behaves like the 'Deprecation Errors' warning on the Dashboard? When active, the widget would appear on all users', or particular user groups, dashboards at the top and display new information, warnings and anything else that may be of use.

Comment: I'm not a plugin developer so I can't help you out here, but there are some docs on the Craft site that might be of help: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/widgets

Comment: I've created Widgets before and that's no problem... I guess the question is more around exposing the widget to users i.e. adding the widget to all users', or  user groups', dashboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no such thing as a “global” widget right row, however your widget’s `getBodyHtml()` method can return `false`, which tells Craft to not show the widget at all. So you could just have the widget assigned to all the user accounts you want, and always return `false` unless there’s actually something to display.